# how to speed up python code from 2.5 to 30 FPS or more in real time video?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, video, scikit-image

I am trying to detect objects in real time video and need to speed up from 2.5 to 30 frames per second (FPS) or more. Unfortunately, it requests 30 FPS at least to work well.

Have any way to speed up it?

Full code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from imutils.video import FPS
# capturing video through webcam
import time
from skimage.morphology import disk
from skimage.filters.rank import entropy
from skimage.filters import threshold_otsu
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
# video dimension in python-opencv
width = cap.get(3)  # float
height = cap.get(4)  # float
print width, height
time.sleep(2.0)
fps = FPS().start()
while (1):
    _, img = cap.read()

    if _ is True:
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        # img =cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    else:
        continue
    kernal = np.ones((5, 5))
    # entropy_img = entropy(img, disk(10))
    entropy_img = entropy(img, kernal)
    # print type(entropy_img), entropy_img
    thresh = threshold_otsu(entropy_img)
    # print thresh
    # binary = entropy_img <= thresh
    ret1, th1 = cv2.threshold(entropy_img, thresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)




    # cv2.imshow("img", img)
    # cv2.imshow("median", median)
    cv2.imshow("threshold", th1)
    # cv2.imshow("kernel", g_kernel)
    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
    fps.update()
    fps.stop()
    print("[INFO] elapsed time: {:.2f}".format(fps.elapsed()))
    print("[INFO] approx. FPS: {:.2f}".format(fps.fps()))
```

**Note:** I have GPU (1050).

Comment: What are dimensions of your images?

Comment: It is 640.0 x 480.0

Comment: What spec machine are you running this on - in terms of CPU make/model and number of cores, and in terms of RAM? Also, what OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because of the size of your image. Skimage entropy is a little expensive.
By this point of view, you have two options:

1. Lower your image resolution, if it's a possibity
2. Slice you image in pieces, process each of it in parallel using your video card and then merge it all again.

For the second option, maybe you will have to slice the image in 12~15 pieces.

This might be helpful to make things work in parallel: https://devblogs.nvidia.com/numba-python-cuda-acceleration/

Comment: Thanks for your information. Maybe I need to find another algorithm instead of Skimage entropy, right?

Comment: What are you trying to do with in general? Find other similar algorithm probably won't work. You can try another approach to solve the same problem.

Comment: My goal, I try to extract image texture in real-time, then joint it with color feature by online training.

Comment: 640 x 480 size? Is that native? There's something up with the operations that you are performing. A frame of 640 x 480 should not be the cause of those FPS drops. The `entropy` function seems suspicious Maybe you can comment out this function to see if this is the cause of the bottleneck.

Comment: I tried that using 640 x 480, then I will use region of interesting (RIO). RIO will be dynamical region (it will change its area) according to person's motion. For camera resolution, I can not change it at all because its specification (Orbbec camera).

Comment: For the entropy function, I am sure that it cause of the bottleneck. Without entropy function, we can get 30 FPS for the same code.

Answer (score 0):

wow you have a powerful gpu. i suggest you to use opencv dnn or cuda to improve the fps